# Remove specific parameters from URL while leaving others intact

Tags: php, laravel, url, parameters

I have a few filters on my view which a user can select. Let's say in this example it is a webshop and the user is viewing a page to buy t-shirts. On the sidebar the user can select a few parameters which will be added to the URL:

```
https://www.myshop.com/shirts?size=22&gender=male&somethingelse=true
```

Now when the user clicks on `view all sizes`, I want the `size=22` to be removed from the URL while keeping the other parameters intact:

```
https://www.myshop.com/shirts?gender=male&somethingelse=true
```

I found somewhere to do that, I have to do the following in my blade file (Mind you I need to do this from the blade view, not from any controller or helper method):

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.shirts', http_build_query(request()->except('size'))) }}">View all sizes</a>
```

But this does not work, it keeps the `size=22` in the URL. What am I missing here, or is there perhaps a different approach to this?

Edit: Added dump of `request()`

[image]

In my example I am using a webshop but in my actual site I am using `date` and `category`, but the base functionality is the same.

Comment: check where you change on the blade and set it to null when you click on `view all sizes`  and I think in your controller you test on it's value

Comment: I am using it BEFORE using the controller, results are being filtered before the controller so I need to do it in the blade view

Comment: Why does filtering happen before the controller? Are you deliberately trying to violate MVC principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this did work after all:

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.shirts', http_build_query(request()->except('size'))) }}">View all sizes</a>
```

I think I did something wrong in the beginning. After revisiting this solution, it worked.

Comment: So, what is the final solution, just to know.

Comment: you should not need the `http_build_query` part ... if you are passing an associative array to `route` it will make create query string parameters for all keys that are not route parameters